# default username in Elastic cloud (kibana) and how to find a password

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elastic-cloud

I'm trying out the Elastic Cloud 14 days free trial.

I deployed Elastic cloud following the video tutorial. I set my password. However, I don't remember putting in my username. I tried my email account, which I used to confirm. I tried my IP address, cloud ID given in my cloud.elastic.co site. I went through account and profile tab but couldn't find anything. I searched for default username, but some site mentioned 'kibana' but that didn't work either.  I am very embarrassed, but I only have 14 days to try it out, so if anyone has used or has been using this, could you help me with this?

**Where else should I look for username? I didn't set my username at all. What is the default username if any?**

[image]

> I modified the question a little bit.

Comment: Have you tried `elastic` ?

Comment: @Val sorry, that doesn't work either :(

Comment: @Val you are right. thank you very much. I had to find a password. The password I set earlier was for something else, so I got confused. I'll edit my questions a little bit to help someone like me :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It took me more than half an hour to figure this out, so hope this will save your time.

So the default user name is **elastic**. (Thank you Val, you are right!) That is the superuser.

However, my password didn't work. So the password I set earlier was for something else. I had to find a password. From my deployment menu, go to **Security** and reset the password and copy it and use it to log in. I attached two screenshots to help you understand.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Amazing how un-intuitive the elastic admin is. Where on earth can we then later see these credentials? I have looked everywhere. Is it only possible to see them when resetting the password? Absurd UX overall.

Answer (score 10):

I faced this situation when playing with elk stack in docker

Default username was: `elastic`.
I could not figure out the password but was able to reset it.

What I did:

- entered elastic container `docker exec -it name_of_elastic_container bash`
- reset password `bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic -i`

Answer (score 1):

**on windows for me it worked just fine**

i run this command to reset the password of elastic user

Generate a password for the elastic user with the `elasticsearch-reset-password` tool. The password is output to the command line.

```
C:\elasticsearch-8.4.0\bin>\bin\elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic
```

reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/zip-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing each of the EKF stack one at a time using helm you can use this command to get the password.

kubectl get secrets --namespace={ namespace installing in } elasticsearch-master-credentials -ojsonpath='{.data.password}' | base64 -d

Default username: elastic

When you helm install elasticsearch from elastic/elasticsearch it generates a password for you to use with Kibana.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Hi when you install elastic it use a multiple users such as "elastic","kibana" and other things

If "elastic" and "changeme" don't work you can reset password with following command in bin folder:

elasticsearch-8.4.0\bin>\bin\elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic

New password print in result.

This is worked for me, i hope work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have never configured the elasticsearch, the password will be displayed in the power shell the first time the elasticsearch runs. You can use this password to log in to Kibana.